# Functions in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Why no missing error ?**

```js
interface User {
  // way 1
  foo(): string;  
  foo2(x:number): string; 

  // way 2
  normal: () => string;
  normal2: (x:number) => string;
}

let user: User = {
  // way 1
  foo: () => '',
  foo2: () => '', // why no error since x is missing
  
  // way 2
  normal: () => '',
  normal2: () => '', // why no error since x is missing
};
```

See this Typescript [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnID0hyA7nAJ7ICM%20yMA9gwBQCUAXMumFKAOYBuAnUYMATMwAe7EAFcAtgCNoHLj35DcdYmUrIxdEAyjy4AG05tkAXgB8a3iEGHjps2MvS5SlTfvdHZwBfLTMIMGRZTChODCxrHG0ScipaAlFLVj9kAHIcgBoRJg9kKztcgqJkgAsqI2RoKGMuUCRkSWRgdGR5LvR%20OiTdKgMCIxNzTOy8wrHXcxKy%20xmqslrkesbm-pA2jq6evoGggSA)

Comment: I tried calling those functions on the `user` and received errors as expected - not sure why there's no error in their definition.

Comment: @AmadouBeye No. There must be some variable which can have a value of undefined. Value does not stay in air but must be in variable only for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **invoke** `(x:number)=>string` without passing in `x`, you get `An argument for 'x' was not provided.` error.

**BUT THIS IS NOT WHAT YOU ARE DOING**

What you are doing is assigning `()=>string` to `(x:number)=>string`, which is valid. When you assign `()=>string` to `(x:number)=>string`, the compiler ask: can `()=>string` behave the same as `(x:number)=>string`?

i.e. can `()=>string` takes in a `number` and spit out a `string`, just like what `(x:number)=>string` do?

The answer is yes, `()=>string` technically can take in any number, but just ignoring it, then return a string, independent of what number it take in. Therefore, `()=>string` is assignable to `(x:number)=>string`

Answer (score 3):

A lower-[arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) function is assignable to a higher-arity one as long as its return type is compatible and the parameters which *are* present are compatible.

In your case, because the functions have no parameters and return a `string`, they are compatible.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwGIDsoF4oAoUC4oqIBGEATgJQYB8UAzsKQJYoDmA3AFAAmEAxgDYBDUtF4B7FPSiNaAYTEIwg4IyL8I+LFkroa9Jq0oQAHsAgoutWIlRQA-FAZxo+AGaD+tCGygB6X46kzhxAA)

```ts
type NumFn = (n: number) => string;
declare const isCompatible: (() => string) extends NumFn ? true : false; // true
```

Comment: Strange. Still why such behavior ? How can we assert it to stop such behavior ?

Comment: @umeshkadam Why would you want to? What's the problem?

Comment: Nothing serious. Just learning. Would be happy to make it more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answers above seems like it can only be detected when you call the function without arguments
my bet is it is something to do with typescript contextual typing
(I too am learning here)

> Function parameters are checked one at a time, with the type in each corresponding parameter position checked against each other. If you do not want to specify types at all, TypeScript’s contextual typing can infer the argument types since the function value is assigned directly to a variable of type SearchFunc. Here, also, the return type of our function expression is implied by the values it returns
> [typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)

```
interface Counter {
  (start: number): string;
  interval: number;
  foo: (x:number) => string;
  bar(x:number):string;
  reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
  let counter = function (s...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsCu5rIN4BQyyAFAM5hxRgBcyImAtgEbQCUdFUoA5gNxFkoSFABucADZ0GLaAOIx06OiQAeNGayhtkAXgB8yLr3nJmVNRqZaOxkP0FQIZCGBIdko9MAAmAgL4EBDDYCGDA6CDIPK4Y2CLudHE4UPiCEq7ICFgpesghIGERUeSU1NLW7Pj+yHBkaDkiptnx0AB0wtDiEnkAjABMAMzNje1OLmB5BUWRpDp4-iOtUG2K6HnueoYA5HY820spbeapunNbyLtg3PYHjq6YUFEtKQFBGZMIeTFgyQlsAgQJF6AAYAQQEG1xq53ICOilunkAKxtEFwtawiHHCwAoA)